# 14.04 Default keyring

Tags: 14.04, password, keyrings

I updated from 12.04 a while ago. Didnt have this problem before.

Once after I log in, and every time I open a browser, and some seemingly random times - I get a `create password for default keyring` type message. I type in my password, confirm it and the next time I open a browser I get the same thing again.

So I open passwords and keys, and try to manually create a keyring called Default, to see if that solves the problem. I get this error: `Couldn't add keyring` with this detail: `No such secret collection at path: /`.

I'd be happy with this keyring thing if it worked, but right now I just want to disable it to get rid of these annoying prompts (at first I thought they were a virus).

Some details:

1. I dont have auto login enabled; I do have password login.
2. Wifi is disabled
3. I have no internet accounts linked
4. I have no Ubuntu One account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after much searching it turns out the directory `~/.local/share/keyrings` had the wrong permissions.

```
chmod 700 ~/.local/share/keyrings
```

should correct it.